# Data8.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client OnPremiseClient On Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory, power-platform, asp.net-core-7.0

I've implemented dynamics 365 sdk using Data8.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client with OnPremiseClient. It works on windows platform perfectly.

But when I deployed it on linux server using docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0` which uses `Debian 11 Bullseye` it requires to install gss-ntlmssp package.
I installed it on the image but when I want to make use of the service the error with bellow stacktrace happens:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()
   at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor(SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, String targetName)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext(SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, ChannelBinding channelBinding, String targetName, ContextFlagsPal inFlags, ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBlob, Byte[]& resultBuffer, ContextFlagsPal& outFlags)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials& credentialsHandle, SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, String spn, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBlob, ChannelBinding channelBinding, Byte[]& resultBlob, Int32& resultBlobLength, ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags)
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatusPal& statusCode)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBlob, NegotiateAuthenticationStatusCode& statusCode)
   at Data8.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ADAuthClient.Authenticate()
   at Data8.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ADAuthClient.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Data8.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.OnPremiseClient.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Ahanonline.Common.DynamicsClient.DynamicsClientService.SetStatus(SetStatusParam param) in /src/Common/DynamicsClient/DynamicsClientService.cs:line 112
   at Ahanonline.Services.OnlineQuotes.OnlineQuotesService.UpdateStatus(UpdateOnlineQuoteStatusRequest body, Requester requester) in /src/Services/OnlineQuotes/OnlineQuotesService.cs:line 48
   at Ahanonline.App.Controllers.OnlineQuotesController.UpdateStatus(UpdateOnlineQuoteStatusRequest dto, Requester requester) in /src/App/Controllers/OnlineQuotesController.cs:line 30
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Ahanonline.Common.Exceptions.Middlewares.AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /src/Common/Exceptions/Middlewares/AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 24
```

Anyone got any idea how to resolve this issue ?

I added an implementation on my github repository. The requirements is that you have an on-premise dynamics 365 to test it.

https://github.com/nimasfl/dotnet7-dynamics-test

Comment: Why not use Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client, is GA now (net core, windows and linux support)? Github: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient. Samples: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/tree/master/dataverse/orgsvc/C%23-NETCore/ServiceClient

Comment: I couldn't create a service using that package for OnPremise Dynamics 365 using DotNet Core. I read through some topics about that and it was said that it is only is available for Online Dynamics 365 usage.